# Yii breadcrumbs переделывает ссылку

Tags: php, yii2

Виджет breadcrumbs переделывает ссылки в постраничной навигации вот в такой вид

```
http://meh-obr.ru/catalog/tokarnye%2Funiversalnye-tokarnye%2Funiversalnye_60?view=table&page=2
```

а должно быть вида:

```
catalog/tokarnye/universalnye-tokarnye/universalnye_60?view=table
```

как быть?

Comment: А какие правила у вас прописаны в UrlManager файла настроек? И как вы хотите различать страницы без параметра `page=2`, ведь 2 разных страницы не могут иметь одинаковые урлы, если пагинация не будет сделана на javascript?

Comment: Прошу прощения, вчера опечатался. на самом деле я имел в виду не breacrumb а LinkPager. Дело было в том что виджет кодировал url, Я залез в виджет Link Pager и при выводе сделал urddecode. Не знаю может быть костылем считается, но работает.

Comment: ну возможно из-за вашего urldecode и получаются такие ссылки, недавно делал LinkPager для новостей и прописывал такое правило: `'news/page/<page:\d+>'=> 'news/index',` попробуйте у себя сделать наподобие. И всё такие хотелось узнать, какой урл вы надеетесь получить в итоге?